# XNA: Moving backwards (if statement never occurs)

Tags: c#, xna

Iam having some difficulties with my XNA project; I want to change the level when my main character moves into the left or right corner (going to the next or previous level respectively).
However, due to a problem I cannot seem to understand, the character is not able to go backwards to the previous level (look at the if player.Position.X == 1200 statement - this never occurs). Walking forward seems to work just fine. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
    private void UpdateLevelOne()
    {
        if (player.Position.X == 0)
        {
            showLevelOne = false;
            showLevelTwo = true;
            player.Position = new Vector2(1200, ground - player.Size.Height);
            levelTwo.backgroundVector = new Vector2(-750,0);
        }
    }
    private void UpdateLevelTwo()
    {
        if (player.Position.X <= 250)
        {
            showLevelTwo = false;
            showLevelOne = true;

            player.Position = new Vector2(1200, ground - player.Size.Height);
            levelOne.backgroundVector = new Vector2(-750, 0);
        }
        if (player.Position.X == 1200)
        {
            showLevelTwo = false;
            showLevelOne = true;
            player.Position = new Vector2(10, ground - player.Size.Height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question should really be asking how to debug, as questions like this are solved with a debugger in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try that

```
if (player.Position.X > 1200) 
    //Do Something
```